# How to integrate remember me after successful login using jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

view: login.php

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#login").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            elogin = $("#elogin").val();
            plogin = $("#plogin").val();
            remember_me = $("#remember_me").val();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:{"elogin":elogin,"plogin":plogin,"remember_me":remember_me},
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>redirect",
                success: function(data) {
                    if (typeof data !== 'object') {
                        data = JSON.parse(data);
                    }
                    if (data.redirect) 
                    {
                        window.location.replace(data.redirect);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $(".login_success").html('<p>' + data.error + '</p>');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel" data-mh="log-tab">
    <div class="title h6">Login to your Account</div>
    <form class="content">
        <div class="login_success"></div>
        <div class="row">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="" type="email" id="elogin">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="" type="password" id="plogin">
                    <input name="optionsCheckboxes" id="remember_me" type="checkbox">Remember Me
                </div>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary full-width" id="login">Login</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

controller:

```
public function login_redirect()
{
    $email = $this->input->post('elogin');
    $password = $this->input->post('plogin');
    $remember = $this->input->post('remember_me');
    if($email=='' || $password=='')
    {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'All fields are mandatory. Please fill all details.'));
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('user');
        $where = "email='".$email."' and password='".$password."' and status='1'";
        $this->db->where($where);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
        {
            $result = $query->result_array();
            $this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$result);
            if (!isset($_POST)) 
            {
                header ("Location:".base_url()."thankyou");
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo json_encode(array('redirect' => base_url().'thankyou'));
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Wrong email or password or may be your account not activated.'));
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, I am creating a login module which works fine. Now, I also want to integrate the `remember me` option when user check `remember me` checkbox server ask to want to save detail or not. When user logout it doesn't require to fill it's detailed again inside the login form. Once the user checks on `remember me` checkbox. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Did you try `cookies`?

Comment: No, I have no idea. How to set cookies when login with jquery @M.Hemant

Comment: refer this link [ https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-remember-me-checkbox/ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this by using cookie.
try following code:

```
//php (controller):
//after success login

if($remember){
  //set cookie
  $this->input->set_cookie('email', $email, 86500);
  $this->input->set_cookie('password', $password, 86500); 
}else
{
  //delete cookie
  delete_cookie('email');
  delete_cookie('password');
}
```

view: login.php

```
//set cookie value if checked remember me.
<div class="row">
   <input class="form-control" value="<?php if (get_cookie('email')) { echo get_cookie('email'); } ?>" placeholder="" type="email" id="elogin">
   <input class="form-control" value="<?php if (get_cookie('password')) { echo get_cookie('password'); } ?>" placeholder="" type="password" id="plogin">
   <input name="optionsCheckboxes" id="remember_me" type="checkbox" <?php if (get_cookie('email')) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>>Remember Me
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the cookie with your javascript when you get the response of your ajax call. You should use document.cookie() if you choose this way to do.

If you choose the server side, CodeIgniter have a Cookie Helper. For use it, you have to add it 'cookie' on your autoload. You can load it with this line too :

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
```

when the helper is loaded, you have to create the cookie in your controller like this :

```
  $this->input->set_cookie('cookie_name', $value, time_in_seconds);
```